# Limite de Argumentos no prompt

Tags: python, prompt, argumento

Pessoal estou tendo um problema na passagem de argumentos do Python no DOS, acredito que deva have um limite dos argumentos, o contexto do código é bem mais amplo, maior, mas aqui está um exemplo simples:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Server Args")
parser.add_argument("--x1", type= int, default=0)
parser.add_argument("--x2", type= int, default=0)
parser.add_argument("--x3", type= int, default=0)
parser.add_argument("--x4", type= int, default=0)
parser.add_argument("--x5", type= int, default=0)
parser.add_argument("--x6", type= int, default=0)

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.x1 + args.x2 + args.x3 + args.x4 + args.x5 + args.x6)
```

Se eu passar 1 em todos os argumentos ao meu ver era para dar 6, porém da 4. Vocês já tiveram um problema semelhante? Já fizeram esse teste?

Muita das vezes quando eu procuro a resposta para esse problema só encontro justificativas relativas ao sistema operacional e eu nunca entendo.

Comment: Acho que só faltou dizer como é que você está executando o código (se é pela IDE, linha de comando, etc), para vermos se o problema foi na chamada. Se puder [edit] acrescentando, ajuda. Sobre o _"o contexto do código é bem mais amplo, maior, mas aqui está um exemplo simples"_ é um dos passos fundamentais para uma boa pergunta, legal que já estreou sua participação com bom senso!

Comment: Nesse caso não posso pois o código é confidencial, por isso trouxe um exemplo que representa o ponto central do problema.

Comment: Update: testei seu código e foi tudo bem, veja https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9RPJ.png

Comment: Eu estou executando esse script de exemplo no DOS do Windows fazendo python script_name.py

Comment: Mesmo que não fosse confidencial, sempre pedimos um [mcve] mesmo, de forma à pergunta servir para um público amplo. Num primeiro momento, não foi possível reproduzir o problema (o código funciona, veja https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9RPJ.png), mas se puder editar com a chamada (provavelmente é no ambiente a limitação), a pergunta é reavaliada.

Comment: Se possível, use a opção de editar para por exatamente a chamada do teste feito, os comentários são efêmeros. Com as informações na pergunta mais gente tem como testar e avaliar.

Comment: Entendi! Agradeço a ajuda, se eu reabri esse problema trarei os prints da minha execução mas é interessante saber que o seu funcionou.

Comment: Fiz igual a sua descrição de 1 a 6 e embaralhando a ordem, e está tudo ok, é grande a chance de ser algo de ambiente. Note que pra dados maiores, o CMD tem limite de duzentos e tantos caracteres. A string pode estar indo cortada pro parser. Se constatar que é isso, a solução é jogar os dados em arquivo e ler no python pelo stdin em vez de argumentos (algo como `origemdosdados.exe | processador.py`) de forma que a saida do 1o programa jogue na entrada do script diretamente em vez de usar argumentos

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTcZy.png

Comment: Note que mesmo que não seja possível reproduzir o problema, nada impede de outros ajudarem aqui pelos comentários mesmo. O impedimento de respostas oficiais pelo código estar funcionando é mera organização (não é demérito nenhum, não veja fechamentos por esse lado). E é sempre passível de revisão caso ao [edit] se encaixe no [objetivo do site](/help) (o importante para a pergunta fazer parte permanente do site é que seja util para um público amplo, não só para o autor, por isso também é fundamental o que fez, de publicar um código sucinto, em vez de código que só serve para seu caso)

Comment: Realmente funciona, esse código aparentemente não tinha funcionado na máquina de um amigo meu, ele testou na minha frente, porque dentro do context no nosso projeto eu estava com um problema semelhante e resolvemos criar um exemplo simples pra testar, ai ele criou esse exemplo e testou na máquina dele e não tinha funcionado, não tinha testado na minha, estava me baseando pelo erro do projeto. Agora eu testei na minha e funcionou, agora é reestudar o problema. Agradeço a compreensão.